# How to detect if navigation drawer is open?

Tags: android, android-navigation

The title explains it all. All what I want to do is to know if the navigation drawer is open or not. I searched a lot on the net and found the method `isDrawerOpen(int drawerGravity)`but couldn't find a satisfactory answer which explains how to use it in a method. I would appreciate if anyone explains it to me.

Comment: `boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)`. mDrawerLayout is the drawer and mDrawerList is the listview

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Assuming you have defined a drawerlayout in xml:

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
...
if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
  //drawer is open
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that the drawer is open?

Comment: Though it may be obvious to many, I'd like to point out isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) should be used if the drawer is opened from right (i.e. android:layout_gravity = "right")

Comment: İf you want to close you should add this coment in if staments drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);

Answer (score 36):

```
 mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
            ) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

That listener use:)

Comment: Thanks but I am not using an actionbar with navigation drawer. Just need to use it in a method!

Answer (score 20):

Use:

**[mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#isDrawerOpen%28android.view.View%29)** method

Example:

```
    if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); //CLOSE Nav Drawer!
    }else{
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); //OPEN Nav Drawer!
    }
```

Comment: if drawer is open, open drawer, else close drawer :D

Answer (score 6):

By the following way you can find the Drawer is open or close..

```
 public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);

        DrawerLayout drawer=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(this);
    }//onCreate()

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View arg0) {
      //write your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {
        //write your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View arg0, float arg1) {
        //write your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int arg0) {
        //write your code
    }
}//class
```

Comment: Use addDrawerListener since set is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

Detect `DrawerLayout` opened, closed, slide [DrawerLayout.DrawerListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener)

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout:
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
    /**
     * Called when a drawer's position changes.
     *
     * @param slideOffset The new offset of this drawer within its range, from 0-1
     *                    Example when you slide drawer from left to right, slideOffset will increase from 0 - 1 (0 when drawer closed and 1 when drawer display full)
     */
    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View drawerView) {
        // do something when drawer opened
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View drawerView) {
        // do something when drawer closed
    }

    /**
     * Called when the drawer motion state changes. The new state will
     * be one of {@link #STATE_IDLE}, {@link #STATE_DRAGGING} or {@link #STATE_SETTLING}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

    }
});
```

Check Drawer is opened

```
if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) // or  GravityCompat.END
```

Answer (score 3):

May be, I am late but I can share new updated information.
In given code, I set open/close drawer in onclick function.If drawer isopen than it willbe closed else open.This solution is based on RXava DrawerLayout [**`(androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout)`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/drawerlayout).
In my code I open drawerlayout from right to left.

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

  if (drawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.END)) {
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
  }else {
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
  }

}
```

Note: If you open drawerLayout from right side use **"GravityCompat.END"** and it is open from left side, than use **"GravityCompat.START"**.
Enjoy codding.....

Answer (score 2):

shakeJ's answer its the correct one, and remember you can use the *onDrawerSlide* to be able to fire other functions... for example I used it to change the StatusBar Color.

```
        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            isOpen = false;
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            isOpen = true;
        }
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView,float slideOffset){
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView,slideOffset);
            if(!isOpen){
                setStatusBarColor("#00102b");
            }
            if(isOpen){
                setStatusBarColor("#EFEFF0");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The method is the same in Kotlin.

1. Initialize the [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout) View

   `val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)`
2. Check if the drawer is open

   `if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
           Log.d("Drawer","open")
    }`

If you want to take actions automatically when the drawer is opened or closed, you can do the following.

1. In your main activity, create an inner class that is a subclass of [DrawerLayout.DrawerListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener). The DrawerLayout class implements the DrawerListener interface.

   ```
   inner class CustomDrawer : DrawerLayout.DrawerListener{
     override fun onDrawerStateChanged(newState: Int) {
     }

     override fun onDrawerSlide(drawerView: View, slideOffset: Float) {
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(drawerView?.getWindowToken(), 0)
     }

     override fun onDrawerClosed(drawerView: View) {
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(drawerView?.getWindowToken(), 0)
     }

     override fun onDrawerOpened(drawerView: View) {
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(drawerView?.getWindowToken(), 0)
     }
   }
   ```
2. Put your action in the function you want to use. In my example, I'm closing the soft keyboard if the user interacts with the navigation drawer. Declare the InputMethodManager like this in your main activity:

   `var imm: InputMethodManager = this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)`
3. Add your custom DrawerListener to the drawerLayout (I put it in the onCreate method)

   `var drawerListener = CustomDrawer()`
   `drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerListener)`