# Is it possible to detect events when user interacts with app drawer (Android)?

Tags: android

I wonder if there is some method to detect when an android user opens/closes the application drawer in his phone. Also, if the user has a folder in the homescreen, is there some kind of log event that detects this interaction?

I need to get that information in my application.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633791/how-to-detect-if-navigation-drawer-is-open

Comment: I think this link is not what I'm searching for. I mean, this is for a navigation drawer, but I need to know when the user opens the application drawer (system drawer).

DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

I don't know how to "invoke" the system drawer, not a drawer that I create in my layout,

Comment: Forget it. There are hundreds of launcher app, and you would need to have a rooter phone to read the logs of other apps.

Comment: It's not a problem to have a rooter phone, it's for a personal app. But I don't understand which other apps are involved here. I want to read information from the "system" (or maybe I'm wrong, not sure).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can...

you have to implement the `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener` for drawer layout

```
public abstract void onDrawerClosed (View drawerView)
```

Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state.
Parameters

```
public abstract void onDrawerOpened (View drawerView)
```

Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state.

```
public abstract void onDrawerSlide (View drawerView, float slideOffset)
```

Called when a drawer's position changes.

```
public abstract void onDrawerStateChanged (int newState)
```

Called when the drawer motion state changes.

Comment: The problem, it's that I don't know how to receive that info, when user press the "system button" that opens the applications draw, not a personal navigation drawer created for me.

I need to know what I have to write to "call" that drawerView