# How to check whether the navigation drawer is open?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer

I have an activity with navigation drawer. Below is my code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if(dLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)==true) {
                 dLayout.closeDrawers();
                }

            else
            {
            doExit();
            }
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private void doExit() {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                FirstSelection.this);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

According to this code, when the user presses back button, the navigation drawer is closed if it is opened, else the `doExit();` method is called. But in my case, the else condition works fine, but when I press back button when the drawer is open, the complete app closes. I followed this code [How to detect if navigation drawer is open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633791/how-to-detect-if-navigation-drawer-is-open)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DrawerLayout` has method `isDrawerOpen(listView)` returns true or false this will help you I guess

```
if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
```

Add above code inside onBackPressed

Comment: **if(dLayout.isDrawerOpen(dList)==true){
    dLayout.closeDrawers();
   }** used this, still same problem

Comment: does this affects onKeyDown() method??

Comment: share your code inside oncreate related to drawer or compare it with drawer sample code I guess you are doing something wrong there

Comment: plus check if you are calling  super.onBackPressed(); try commenting it and check

Answer (score 1):

Here are the general steps for doing this in Kotlin.

1. Initialize the [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout) View

   ```
   val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
   ```
2. Check if the drawer is open

   ```
   if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
       Log.d("Drawer","open")
   }
   ```

If you want to take actions automatically when the drawer is opened or closed, you can do the following.

1. In your main activity, create an inner class that is a subclass of [DrawerLayout.DrawerListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener). The DrawerLayout class implements the DrawerListener interface.

   ```
   inner class CustomDrawer : DrawerLayout.DrawerListener{
     override fun onDrawerStateChanged(newState: Int) {
     }

     override fun onDrawerSlide(drawerView: View, slideOffset: Float) {
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(drawerView?.getWindowToken(), 0)
     }

     override fun onDrawerClosed(drawerView: View) {
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(drawerView?.getWindowToken(), 0)
     }

     override fun onDrawerOpened(drawerView: View) {
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(drawerView?.getWindowToken(), 0)
     }
   }
   ```
2. Put your action in the function you want to use. In my example, I'm closing the soft keyboard if the user interacts with the navigation drawer. Declare the InputMethodManager like this in your main activity:

   ```
   var imm: InputMethodManager = this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)
   ```
3. Add your custom DrawerListener to the drawerLayout (I put it in the onCreate method)

   ```
   var drawerListener = CustomDrawer()
   drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerListener)
   ```